# How to get the full directory in java with the file name

Tags: java, swing, awt, java.util.scanner, bluej

How to get the file Directory plus the full name so i can assign it to the variable inFile
below are the type of data i want to read i have used the regular expression but it did not works

```
public void loadAfileFinal()  throws FileNotFoundException
    {

       Fiog fileBox = new FileD(ileDialog);
       fox.sVisle(true);
       while(scanner.hasNext())
       {
           String name = scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.println(name);
       }
    }
```

Comment: What is `FileDialog`?

Comment: This is very unclear. What are the lines about cars for?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad i assume one of [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html).

Comment: All what i want to know is how to get the full directory of a file plus the name of the file so i can display it in the terminal

Comment: You could use FileDialog#getFiles which will return an array of File, which will make it easier to determine the path and name of the  selected files

Answer (score 2):

Read the [`File`'s JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). Here are some methods that you should consider:

- [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)
- [`getAbsoluteFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile%28%29)
- [`getAbsolutePath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29)
- [`getCanonicalFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile%28%29)
- [`getCanonicalPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29)
- [`getParentFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29)
- [`getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29)

---

Also, as aside advice, consider using [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)(Swing) instead of [`FileDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html)(AWT), unless you are working on a legacy GUI application.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to read and "split" those lines then this should do the job:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    name = name.trim();

    if (!name.isEmpty() || name.startsWith("//")) {
        System.out.println("next item:");
        String[] parts = name.split(",");
        for (String part : parts) {
            System.out.println("part: " + part);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And if you want to get the absolut path of the file this should do the job:

```
fileBox.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: do you Know when i Select the dada i want to read it does not read it #]

Comment: does this "System.out.println(filename + directoryPath);" give you the correct name of the file ? Then try "File inFile = new File(filename + directoryPath);"

Answer (score 0):

This line:
`File inFile = new File(fileBox.getFile());` 

should be
`File inFile = new File(directoryPath + filename);`